# How to loop a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting JSON via ajax like this

```
{
    "questionTypes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "text",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "rating",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "boolean",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "option",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Staff Courtesy",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Staff Response",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Check In",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Check Out",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Travel Desk",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "category": "default",
            "question": "Door Man",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "category": "client",
            "question": "test question",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "category": "client",
            "question": "test1",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "category": "client",
            "question": "test2",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "category": "client",
            "question": "test2",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "category": "client",
            "question": "ggggg",
            "deleted": false,
            "version": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the name fields from

```
"questionTypes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "text",
        "deleted": false,
        "version": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rating",
        "deleted": false,
        "version": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "boolean",
        "deleted": false,
        "version": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "option",
        "deleted": false,
        "version": 0
    }
],

$.each(data1.data.questionTypes, function(index, currPat) {

                   console.log(currPat.name); }
```

but it did not work ,I get undefined in console.Can any body tell me how to loop exactly

Comment: I don't see any `username` properties...?

Comment: What is this `username` you're trying to print out? It looks like `name` in your JSON?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sorry its name

Comment: @EvanKnowles yes I want name

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/497Tx/

Comment: Change `console.log(currPat.username); ` to  `console.log(currPat.name); `. Things should be fine. Are you facing issues after that? Or any other issue?

Comment: @Bhavik Thanks for the fiddle,I need question field from data root and each row having a drop down menu and the options will be from questionTypes roots

Comment: @Popeye yes I find problems.I need each row should be from data root so I did ` $.each(data1.data, function(index, currPat) {
              
              
              tRow += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="cd" value=""/></td>';
              tRow += '<td>'+currPat.question+'</td>';` and now each row should be having a drop down menu having options from questiontypes root

Comment: You have `data` and `questionTypes` on the same level on your json response, so why you're trying to get `questionTypes` as a child of `data` field, consequently, you have to do this: `data1.questionTypes`, you got `undefined` values because there's no field named `questionTypes` inside `data` field.

Comment: @FaresM. Its my requirement,the drop down options I am getting from database so i am using JSON

Comment: @JqueryLearner is [this what](http://jsfiddle.net/497Tx/3/) you want

Comment: @Bhavik yes my requirement is you have designed the fiddle but you have changed the JSON format

Comment: I don't think I did changed any json format of yours...

Comment: @Bhavik I tried your way but its not working for me.Can you come to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners)

Comment: @JqueryLearner i know, but this is not about using JSON or not, you're trying to access a field that doesn't exist on your JSON object hierarchy, so iterating `data1.data.questionTypes` will not give any values because it's `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/497Tx/3/)***</kbd>

*jQuery*

```
$.each(json.data, function (index, currPat) {
    $(tbody).append('<tr><td><b>Question from data: ' + currPat.question + '</b></td><td><b>Names from questionTypes</b><select class="qType"></select></td></tr>');
});

var select = $('.qType');
$(json.questionTypes).each(function (index, currPat) {
    $(select).append('<option>' + currPat.name + '</option>');
});
```

You must loop twice: *Once* for getting the `question` and *then* for getting `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.I will have a look

Comment: @JqueryLearner chat link..?

Answer (score 2):

OK, you can do this ,

```
$(jsonObject.questionTypes).each(function(i,value){
     //get value here using value.name
     alert(value.name);
 });
```

And the problem was you were actually extracting `questionTypes` from `data`which is non existent there.

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm2GN/1/)**

data has no questionTypes

```
$.each(data1.questionTypes, function(index, currPat) {

                      alert(currPat.name);


    });
```

Comment: @downvoters could you tell me the reason for downvote  then only i rectify my error

Comment: I need each row should be from data root so I did ` $.each(data1.data, function(index, currPat) { tRow += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="cd" value=""/></td>'; tRow += '<td>'+currPat.question+'</td>';` and now each row should be having a drop down menu having options from questiontypes root

Answer (score 0):

in your code I don't see any **username** properties, 
try to use this code.

```
$.each(data1.data.questionTypes, function(index, currPat) {

               console.log(currPat.name); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(json.questionTypes, function (index, currPat) {
    div=$('<div/>').text(currPat.name);
    $('#jsoncontainter').append(div);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/497Tx/1/

For your second part of the problem, here is a solution.

```
$.each(json.data, function (index, currQuest) {
    question=$('<div/>',{'class':'question'}).text(currQuest.question);
    answer=$('<div/>',{'class':'answer'});
    dropdown=$('<select/>');
    $.each(json.questionTypes, function (index, currPat) {
        option=$('<option/>').text(currPat.name).appendTo(dropdown);
    });
    answer.append(dropdown);
    $('#jsoncontainter').append(question).append(answer);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/497Tx/4/)**

Comment: I want to show question from data root as row and each row should be having one drop down and that drop will have options from questionType.So how to do?

Comment: What is data root? Can you create a fiddle with the JSON assuming you are creating the question and dropdown options from the JSON.

Comment: under data you will find questions like Staff Courtesy,test2 .... .So this will be row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54433/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-rupam-datta).